# Issue with Global Install of Ngrok in MacOS and Arch Linux with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm-install, ngrok

**Issue that I am facing:**

I am trying to install ngrok globally on my MacOS. But when I install it gives me this:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ngrok@3.2.5 postinstall: `node ./postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ngrok@3.2.5 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/careaxiom/.npm/_logs/2019-10-23T10_16_49_550Z-debug.log
```

same with `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its kind of in discussion on gitHub whats causing it but this works just fine for now

```
sudo npm install -g ngrok --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```